# Macbook Pro 2020 doesn't recognize second monitor while using usbc

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I want my MacBook pro-2020 to be closed and have one screen as the main screen(desktop) and the other screen as an extended one. I have 2 new Dell UltraSharp U2419HC monitors, and an UltraSharp U2419H (non-usbc).

I have connected one screen to my MacBook using type c to type c cable (from screen to MacBook) and another display port cable from one screen to another one.

It looks like either my mac detects only one screen, or either I can't get an extended view over the 2 Dell screens.

Currently, the 2 Dell screens display the same thing, my Desktop. When I open my MacBook screen, it detects it's own screen and the Dell screen that is attached with the USB c on extended mode but doesn't detect the second Dell monitor.

When I get into the System Pref -> Displays I can only see the Dell monitor that is connected with USB c.

I have also tried to connect the USB c to a Dell laptop and it did work, so I assume it's not a connectivity issue, and furthermore when I'm connecting the second Dell screen using HDMI cable type c to my MacBook (overall 2 Dell monitors connected directly to my MacBook) it works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this to show the full marketing name of your Mac? It’s in about this Mac window under the version number of the OS. Most displays do not daisy chain so I’m looking to recommend other connector based on your precise model...

Answer (score 1):

Daisy-chaining monitors over USB-C is not supported on macOS. This is due to the fact that macOS does not support MST for monitor daisy-chaining, unlike for example Microsoft Windows. You will need to use Thunderbolt monitors in order to get display daisy-chaining working.

With your current hardware, you need to connect each monitor to its own port on the MacBook Pro - or get a Thunderbolt 3 dock that allows you to connect two monitors to the dock, and then the dock via one cable to the MacBook Pro.